# Multiview Application

Tags: iphone

I am trying to develop an engineering program. My first view has a textfield where the user is required to enter "e" or "s", for the units to be used(english or si), which is stored in a variable es. The AppDelegate shows this first view through applicationDidFinishLaunching: method. I have a Objective-C source file, where I am writing my code. How do I load the next view with a number of textfields where the user has to enter some values to be saved in variables?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be to build a Navigation Controller on the App Delegate.  Then you can easily push and pop views onto and off of the Controller.  Something like this (this would work well inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching` of your App Delegate):

```
// controller is defined in the header
controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
...
// Build your UIView
SomeUIView *welcome = [[SomeUIView alloc] initWithNibName: @"Welcome" bundle: nil];
[controller pushViewController: welcome animated: NO];
[welcome release];
...
// Display the Controller's top view in the window
[window addSubview: controller.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then to change Views (this code is applicable anywhere in your application):

```
SomeOtherView *Detail = [[SomeOtherView alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: Detail animated:YES];
[Detail release];
```

Notice you can always get back to the Navigation Controller through "`self`".

Good Lick!